# Elasticsearch query associations returning no results

Tags: elasticsearch, associations

I have a data model that belongs to a category model. This data model therefore associates with a `category_id` column. My query is processed by ES but it is returning no results.

I have fabricated a record, took its `category_id`, and passed in the `category_id` to the query below. I expected at least one result because it is the same `category_id`. However, I am getting 0 results.

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        bool: {must: []},
      },
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            term: {category_id: #CATEGORY_ID PASSED IN HERE}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  sort: [{
    _geo_distance: {
      store_location: {:lat=>0, :lon=>0},
      order: "asc",
      unit: "miles"
    }
  }]
}
```

This is my current mapping. There are properties here that may be irrelevant because it's from a large project.

```
"test-somethings": {
  "mappings": {
    "something": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "bpid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "category_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "listings": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
          "properties": {
            "store_id": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "store_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "store_location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Some data I am testing with:

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "bpid":"84202e8fc0",
  "name":"Something",
  "description":"Labore et odit quas sit similique. Molestiae deserunt rem harum assumenda voluptate placeat est. Reiciendis iusto ea et. Nesciunt qui et ab porro vitae ut. Exercitationem et dolores ullam.",
  "created_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "category_id":1282
},
  "id":2,
  "bpid":"9719093ac5",
  "name":"Test Something",
  "description":"Dolores minima fugit sunt. Consequuntur aspernatur dolorem. Quasi dolorem natus occaecati eos culpa error. Voluptates dolores pariatur ab impedit minima cumque molestiae.",
  "created_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "category_id":1283
},
  "id":3,
  "bpid":"5026503fc5",
  "name":"Pot",
  "description":"Et facilis et voluptatem amet. Quidem qui molestiae quia voluptas voluptatum. Facilis aut illo dicta provident animi omnis. Et quia dicta omnis aliquam quas sequi. Nemo sed officia consequatur excepturi.",
  "created_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-05-01T21:02:23.000Z",
  "category_id":1284
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        match_all: {},
      },
      filter: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            term: {category_id: #CATEGORY_ID PASSED IN HERE}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  sort: [{
    _geo_distance: {
      store_location: {:lat=>0, :lon=>0},
      order: "asc",
      unit: "miles"
    }
  }]
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e538630b18e499a1bc566896413627b540aae745

Comment: It still returned 0 results. What was the reasoning behind this? All I see it that query contains `match_all` instead of `bool` and `must`. In the end, this portion is empty anyways.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the syntax was wrong, but apparently not. I guess it's okay to have an empty bool query, though it's obviously redundant. Turns out ES treats an empty "must" like a "match_all" (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7240). So you're right, that's not the problem. But you didn't post your mapping or any data, so it's hard to tell what your actual problem is. Both queries work for me.

Comment: I added the mapping and some data I am testing with in the question.

Comment: And the test scenario you posted reproduces your error? When I try it your query works. Here is the code I used: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/8c2bc41a54acd502ca3ade2deb86182a0d78a301

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the geo distance sorting. I didn't try it with that intact.

Comment: Also I'm using ES 1.5.0. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: I am using ES 1.5.1. and I tried your code. Strangely, it is not returning any hits for me. I highly doubt it's a problem with ES versions.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't think a minor version difference would cause it. Strange that it works for me and doesn't for you, though.

Comment: If I get time later tonight I'll test the code against both versions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tested the query on numerous machines. All failed. I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: I just tested it against ES 1.5.1 in a Vagrant Ubuntu VM, and the last sense code I posted worked fine. Both queries returned the expected document. So I have no idea what's going on with your setup, I'm sorry.